# Button text rotate incorrect work with tag singleLine

Tags: android, button, canvas, rotation

I have a button:

```
public class MyButton extends Button{
       private float degrees;
       public MyButton(Context context) {
           super(context);
       }

       public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
           super(context, attrs, defStyle);
       }

       public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
           super(context, attrs);
       }

       @Override
       protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
           canvas.save();
           canvas.rotate(degrees, this.getWidth()/2, this.getHeight()/2);
           super.onDraw(canvas);
           canvas.restore();
       }

       protected void rotateTextInButton(float degrees){
           this.degrees = degrees;
       }
}
```

then i create a button `MyButton mBtn = new MyButton(this)` and when i use `mBtn.setSingleLine(true)`, method `rotateTextInButton()` works only on `0` and `360` degrees.

If remove `mBtn.setSingleLine(true)` from code - all works currectly.

It's possible to solve this?

P.S. I MUST use single line at button and able to rotate text inside a button.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `mBtn.setSingleLine(true)` , use `mBtn.setHorizontallyScrolling(true)`. Hope, this will help u...

Comment: `mBtn.setHorizontallyScrolling(true)` repeat prevision situation.

Comment: "best alternate" of what?)))

Comment: Repeat: it's not solve the problem. Partially solve my problem next code `mBtn.setMaxLines(1); mBtn.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);`, but it not what i wanted. I mean if i have a button with text `blablabla` and when i use  large text size i get that situation https://www.dropbox.com/s/lph7lv71dze6lwr/what_i_get.png, but i need that: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gf8pmwy3glusvod/what_i_need.png